# テーマの編集でAtomが起動できなくなった際の対処法

Tags: atom-editor

[image]
使用OS:　Mac OS X El Capitan バージョン10.11.6
Atomを使用中、インストールしたThemeでコードの色を変更したいと考え、自分でファイルの中身を編集したのですが再起動後から上記の画像のようになり起動しなくなりました。

私としてもファイル名を記載したいところですが、あまり確認せずにファイルを編集したためあまり覚えていません・・・
外部よりインストールしたthemeで、HTMLの表示色を部分的に変えたいと思いlessファイルを編集しました。 
うろ覚えですがbass.lessのようなファイルと他2つほどファイルの編集をしたと思います。
lessファイル上では「@black」のような形でカラーコードの追加と対応していると思われる部分を変更しました。
おそらくその際に変えてはいけない部分を変更してしまったのかと思います。 
ファイル名もうろ覚えという状態ですので、もし似たような状態になった方いたらで結構です。 お気づきの点ありましたら教えていただきたいです。 
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Atom のことは知らないのでお役には立てませんが，一般的にどのようなファイルの中身をどのように編集したのかくらいは書いたほうがいいんじゃないかとおもいます．

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。すみません、大変初歩的なことだと思うのですがatomコマンドを導入していませんでした・・・外部からapmコマンドだけ導入は可能でしょうか？

Comment: `atom`コマンドは`/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh
` へのリンクで、`apm`コマンドは`/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/atom-package-manager/bin/apm`へのリンクのようですね。これらを直接実行すればよさそうですが、私の手元には環境がないので、新しく質問される方がよいと思います。

Comment: また、自分の投稿へのコメントでの情報の追記は、誰の目にも止まりません。情報の追加は質問の編集で行なって下さい。特定の回答に関し回答者にコメントしたい場合は、その回答に直接コメントして下さい。もちろん、新しい質問が生まれた場合は、新しく質問を投稿して下さい。

Comment: すみません、ご丁寧にありがとうございます。初めて使うのでどのようにしていいかわかりませんでした。新しく質問したいと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### セーフモードでの起動

`--safe`オプションを付けて起動すると、標準以外のパッケージを読み込みません。

```sh
atom --safe
```

これで起動して、今回の例ですとテーマを他の物に設定するなどの、対処を行います。

#### apm コマンドによるパッケージの削除・無効化

```sh
apm uninstall パッケージ名
```

`apm`の`uninstall`で`atom`を起動せずにパッケージを削除出来ます。
`disable`で無効化です。
今回の例ですと問題はテーマなので、無効化しても読み込みが生じ、意味が無いかもしれません。
パッケージ名が分からない場合は、

```sh
apm list
```

でインストール済みのパッケージが確認出来ます。
テーマに絞って見るなら、

```sh
apm list -t
```

とします。

Comment: 解決しました！！！本当に助かりました。ありがとうございました。今後は軽い気持ちで内部ファイルの編集はしないようにします。